# Superimposing Multiple HTML Canvases with unique CSS Styles on top of Eachother

Tags: html, css

I'm new to stackoverflow and programming.

I'm designing a website right now and was wondering if someone could help me figure out how stack multiple HTML canvases on top of eachother, each with their own CSS style attached.

Right now I have a square in the middle of the page with a CSS style attached to it that establishes it's size, animates its growth, etc. I want this to be the top layer of several, larger squares that have the same effect (i.e. a series of concentric squares that all expand slightly when moused over.)

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link href="hvr-grow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="hvr-grow2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body onLoad="draw();">
        <div>
        <canvas class="hvr-grow" id="magazine 1"></canvas> </div>
        <div> <canvas class="hvr-grow2" id="magazine 2"></canvas> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
 @charset "UTF-8";
/* Hover-Grow */

.hvr-grow {
    background-color: #CCC;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: -225px 0 0 -225px; 
}

.hvr-grow:hover,
.hvr-grow:focus,
.hvr-grow:active {
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
```

And

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Hover-Grow 2 */

.hvr-grow {
    background-color: #000;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px; 
    z-index: 2;
}

.hvr-grow:hover,
.hvr-grow:focus,
.hvr-grow:active {
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
```

I was thinking canvas style = "z-index: ..." might be helpful, but I'm not sure how to implement that in this case.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think we can replicate this if you don't add the rest of your markup.. try to do it on the code snippets here or on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Do you mean the markup for the rest of the boxes I want to create? The HTML and CSS above are all I have so far, they produce the 1 square that grows when you hover over it when you load them in a browser.

Comment: You mentioned overlaying more divs, so I guessed you'd add them in the HTML too.

Comment: I see, okay, I'll try to add what I'm thinking for those and get back to you.

Comment: Okay, so I thought this code would show the bigger square (hvr-grow.css applied to canvas id "magazine 1") behind the smaller square (hvr-grow.css applied to canvas id "magazine 2"), but instead it's only showing the smaller square.

Comment: Just a sec, adding the code below

Comment: Add it to the question, I'm not going to re-format all that stuff!!

Comment: Added to the question now. Sorry, still getting used to this forum set up.

Comment: Actually, think I figured out how to do it, just had to add a "2" to the end of all of the .hvr-grow instances in the second CSS file to differentiate them.